# html template file isn't found Angular 5

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have Angular 5 app with systemjs.config.js file.

Structure of files is the following:
`app` folder contains `main.ts, app.compoment.ts, app.component.html, app.module.ts, app-routing.module.ts` files.

`systemjs.config.js`:

```
paths: {
    'npm:': "libs/"
},
map: {
    app: "app",
    ...
},
packages: {
    app: {
        main: "./main.js",
        defaultExtension: "js"
    },
    ...
}
```

When I put path as relative:

`templateUrl: './app.component.html'`

I have error `{domain}/app.component.html` not found. `{domain} = http://localhost:1234`

But if I put absolute path:

`templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'`

it works fine.

What should I do to get relative paths working?

Comment: what is `{domain}`??

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Added SystemJS plugin (systemjs-angular-loader.js) to  SystemJS
>   configuration. This plugin dynamically converts "component-relative"
>   paths in templateUrl and styleUrls to "absolute paths" for you.
>
> I strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. You
>   no longer need to write @Component({ moduleId: module.id }), nor
>   should you.

**angular quickstart**

```
meta: {
  './*.js': {
    loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
  }
}
```

[systemjs.config](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/systemjs.config.js#L34-L38)

**angular-cli**

To align with @angular/core behavior, all templateUrl and styleUrls are now treated as relative - developers should use the ./foo.html form in all cases.

See also

[Relative template and style urls using system js without moduleid in angular](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3241-relative-template-and-style-urls-using-system-js-without-moduleid-in-angular-2-4-9.htm)

**PREVIOUS VERSION**

By default, you should specify **the full path back to the application root**. It is **absolute with respect to the application root**.

It may be:

```
@Component({
   templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html' // or src
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

If you want to specify template and style URLs relative to their component class files you should set moduleId property to decorator of your component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id
  templateUrl: './app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

If you use SystemJS, then it should be __moduleName variable instead of the module.id variable:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  templateUrl: './app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

[Component relative paths in angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html)